# CentOS 6. Three NICs, Three Subnets, Non Converged Network and ARP requests

Tags: centos, routing, ip, subnet, arp

I couldn't find any existing questions that fit mine so I hope this is not a duplicate but I have some rather strange behavior. I have this same set up running on Oracle Solaris (SPARC) without this issue, just my Cent boxes.

CentOS box has 3 NICS:

```
P2P1: 192.168.1.2/24 Default Gateway 192.168.1.1 [MAC A]
P2P2: 192.168.2.2/24 No default gateway (isolated network and switches) [MAC B]
P2P3: 192.168.3.2/24 No default gateway (isolated network and switches) [MAC C]
```

My netstat -rn

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface


192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 p2p3
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 p2p2
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 p2p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 p2p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 p2p2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 p2p3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 p2p4
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 p2p1
```

As a user (192.168.1.3/24), I cannot ping or traceroute to 192.168.2.2 or 192.168.3.2 which is exactly what I want. In theory, if I assign myself an alias IP of 192.168.2.2/24 (I KNOW THIS IS THE IP OF p2p2), I shouldn't have any issues because my machine has no physical access to the switches that P2P2 connects to, but lo and behold, I get an IP conflict.

The real problem, is that if I run an ARP scan for 192.168.2.2... I get an ARP response from MAC A as if P2P1 is responding on behalf of P2P2.

I wouldn't actually want to assign myself this as an alias I just did so to show the dilema. How do I stop P2P1 from responding to requests for P2P2. I know this is a typical issue when you have multiple NICs on the same subnet but that is not the case here.